# react: многократная инициализация внутри функционального компонента

Tags: reactjs, компоненты, state, render, usestate

Написал такой отладочный код:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'antd';

// компонент отображения страниц
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    dbgSetValue(old => old + 1);
  }

  // контроль состояний
  const [dbg] = useState(console.log('dbg'));
  const [dbgValue, dbgSetValue] = useState(0);

  // отрисовать компонент
  return (
    <Button onClick={handleClick}>Жми</Button>
  );
}

export default App;
```

каждый раз при нажатии на кнопку выводится `dbg`, т.е. вызывается `useState`.

у меня скорее всего не совсем точное понимание работы функциональных компонент, потому что я думал, что `useState` вызывается однократно при многократных перерисовках компонента, однако похоже это не так.

**Отсюда вопрос:**

Мне необходимо, чтобы вне зависимости от кол-ве отрисовок компонента внутри сохранялось бы некоторое значение. Как это лучше сделать?

Я думал, что смогу использовать useState для однократной инициализации такого значения, например если в качестве параметров передается некоторый класс, то я мог бы создать однократно ВНУТРИ компонента объект класса и работать с ним:

```
[target] = useState(new props.MyTarget)
```

Но очевидно такой подход не работает.
**Как же быть?**

Мне очень не хотелось бы этот объект `target` делать внешним для данного компонента, хотелось бы однократно инициализировать внутри компонента и работать с ним вне зависимости что происходит с компонентом - какие состояния меняются, что делают дочерние компоненты и т.д.

Comment: Так у тебя  const [dbg] = useState(console.log('dbg')); в начальном состоянии не колбек, а вызов функции, поэтому каждый раз при триггере dbgSetValue вызывается console.log
Попробуй useState(()=> new SomeClass)

Comment: @Алексей, `const [value, setValue] = useState(0)` - в каких случаях надо использовать `setValue((old) => ...)`? когда необходимо использовать старое значение, чтоб гарантировать корректность значений? или есть еще варианты?

Comment: @Zhihar Это нужно например, когда хотите одновременно несколько раз обновить значение стейта. Можете почитать [тут](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state)

Comment: @Zhihar да, когда у тебя несколько вызовов  юзстейт в 1 функции(т.к useState - ассинхронная операция) примерчик от  EzioMercer как раз это наглядно иллюстрирует

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо почитать [этот параграф](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#avoiding-recreating-the-initial-state)

Суть в том, что значение в `dbg` не обновляется при каждом рендеринге, но функция сама внутри `useState` вызывается каждый при отрисовке компоненты. Значение функции устанавливается в `dbg` только в первый раз. Чтобы убедиться в этом можем создать `useEffect`, который будет вызываться при обновлении значения `dbg`:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;
const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;

const App = () => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    dbgSetValue(old => old + 1);
  }

  const [dbg] = useState(console.log('dbg'));
  const [dbgValue, dbgSetValue] = useState(0);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Новое знаечние dbg - это', dbg);
  }, [dbg])

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Жми</button>
  );
}

// Рендеринг

const container = document.querySelector('#root');
const root = createRoot(container);
root.render(<App />)
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Но функция может очень трудоёмкой, и потому лучше всего в таких случаях передавать не результат выполнения функции, а саму функцию:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;
const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;

const App = () => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    dbgSetValue(old => old + 1);
  }
  
  const consoleLog1 = () => {
    console.log('dbg1')
  }
  
  const consoleLog2 = () => {
    console.log('dbg2')
  }

  const [dbg1] = useState(consoleLog1());
  const [dbg2] = useState(consoleLog2);
  const [dbgValue, dbgSetValue] = useState(0);

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Жми</button>
  );
}

// Рендеринг

const container = document.querySelector('#root');
const root = createRoot(container);
root.render(<App />)
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```